# How can I set up Samba preserve file ownership on writes to a single Samba share?

Tags: linux, samba

I'd like to edit Solr configuration files on my linux box via a samba share.  The files need to be `tomcat6:mygroup`, but when I edit the files via windows, it writes them as `myuser:mygroup`.  Is it possible to change the write settings for a single samba share so it preserves the existing user, group and permissions?

Is this something that can be done via Samba configuration, or is something trickier needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include an appropriate `force user` statement into your `smb.conf`. I'm assuming your Samba share's name is `smbshare`:

```
[smbshare]
  ....
  force user = tomcat6
  ....
```

You can find out more details via `man smb.conf`. The important points are: *tomcat6* needs to be a user on the system. Your connection to the `[smbshare]` needs to take place with valid user credentials. Once connected all file operations will be performed under the credentials of *tomcat6*  though. (You don't seem to want an additional setting of `force user = ...`, which is also possible....)

**Update:** You said you wanted to *"preserve the existing user, group and permissions"*. Note, that my suggestion doesn't do that. It ***forces*** all edited files to be owned by `tomcat6:mygroup` instead of preserving the original settings. Maybe this is good enough for your purpose.